# Ruby on Rails - Find by SQL adding apostrophes

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have wrote a SQL query which I am using in my model, provided below:

```
Tag.find_by_sql(["SELECT tags.id, tags.name, count(*) AS count FROM tags
    INNER JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
    WHERE 
    (taggings.taggable_type = 'Discussion' AND taggings.taggable_id IN (SELECT id FROM  `discussions` WHERE discussions.group_id = ?))
     GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY ? LIMIT ?;", self.id, self.id, self.id, self.id, order, limit])
```

This works fine and pulls out the required tags.  However the tags do  not order correctly.  I noticed in the server console that the query has apostrophes around the order statement like so:

```
ORDER BY 'count desc'
```

When I remove the apostrophes, like so:

```
ORDER BY count desc
```

and run the query manually it pulls the tags in the correct order.  Is there a way to stop the apostrophes being added to the query?

Cheers

Tony

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because you have parameterized the column name

```
ORDER BY ?
```

The value you have pass has been sanitized that's why it becomes `'count desc'`.

You cannot pass column names and tables name by design. The only way is to concatenate the column name within the string.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks, is it safe enough to do the following: ORDER BY #{order}

Comment: That depends on where `order` is coming from. If it an untrusted input - ie from a user or another source not you, then no.

Comment: I am always setting that myself in the controller.  So I think this approach would be safe but is there another way of doing this, out of curiousity?